# Python cannot find module from command line but works from eclipse

Tags: python, import, python-2.7

I am very new to Python and have strange error. I am using Eclipse/PyDev for development and Python 2.7.3 in eclipse and commandline. I created several modules, every folder has **init**.py file and other source files. When I try to execute file with `__name__ == '__main__'` from eclipse it works fine but from command line when I call like

```
python models.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from database import uuid_generator
ImportError: No module named database
```

it looks like[image]
Can anybody give me clue what can be problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently eclipse has added the database directory to the module search path.

To get the same effect without modifying the script you can append the path to database into $PYTHONPATH environment variable.

If you are open to modifying the script you can add this towards the top after importing relevant modules `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))`

**untested hack**

**see J.F.Sebastian's answer and comment below instead**

Comment: it should be `dirname(dirname(...))` in this case i.e., the parent directory of `database` should be in sys.path, not the `database` directory itself. But it is not a good practice anyway because python adds script's directory to sys.path on start and it might lead to the same module being imported twice under different names  (`__main__` gotcha) that in turn might produce hard to debug bugs connected with global state. The solution is to create a small toplevel wrapper script that calls `main()' function from the internal module.

Answer (score 3):

`database` parent directory is not in `sys.path` (pythonpath). Try to run the script as `python -mdatabase.uuid_generator` while in the parent (toplevel) directory. Or create a wrapper script:

```
from database.uuid_generator import main

main()
```

And put it in `database`'s parent (toplevel) directory. When you call this script its directory is added to `sys.path` automatically so everything works without modifying modules inside `database` directory or `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Only the toplevel directory that has no `__init__.py` in it (not a Python package) need to be in `sys.path` i.e., `database` directory should not be in `sys.path`.

See [Traps for the unwary](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0395/#traps-for-the-unwary).

Answer (score 1):

Try using this instead

```
from uuid_generator
```

edit: make sure uuid_generator.py is in the same folder as models.py

Comment: `from uuid_generator` is not valid Python. Either absolute (`database.uuid_generator`) or explicit relative (`.uuid_generator`) import should be used.